# Bisection method (Numerical analysis)

Tags: matlab, analysis, numerical, newtons-method, bisection

How many recursions are made before every single root is found? Also, which ones are the roots?

Here's my code:

```
e=0.000001; 
f1=@(x) 14.*x.*exp(x-2)-12.*exp(x-2)-7.*x.^3+20.*x.^2-26.*x+12;

a=0; 
c=3; 
while abs(c-a)>e 
    b=(c+a)/2; 
    if f1(a)*f1(b)<0 
        c=b; 
    else
        a=b;
    end    
    disp(b);  
end
```

Comment: So why not add printouts to your recursions and see for yourself?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the internals of your function, so I cannot get into specifics, but why not just print the values of internal variables and identify what values correspond to what root? Alternatively, you can post the algorithm and I'll have a look at it myself.

Comment: Your algorithm finds only one root z=0.857, whereas your function has another one at 2. Also, please refrain from posting links to your code, embed it into the question instead.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious here: you know `fzero`? Also take a look at [this function on the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.nl/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15122-real-roots-on-interval) -- you will learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bisection works by taking endpoints of some initial interval `[a,b]` and finding which half of the interval must contain the root (it evaluates the midpoint, and identifies which half has the sign change).  Then bisection repeats the process on the identified half.

Bisection converges upon only **one** possible root, and if your function has multiple roots inside `[a,b]`, it is difficult to predict in general which specific root it will converge to.  (Note: since bisection is a fully deterministic algorithm, it will always converge to the exact same root if you give it the same initial interval.)  The iterations simply refine your approximation of found root, they do not find multiple roots.

To directly answer your question, bisection **will not** discover all three of the roots of your function inside `[0,3]`.  It will find just one root, and this is identified by the final iteration of your bisection code.  All of the values outputted by the bisection iterations simply show the progress made by the algorithm towards the one root it eventually found (and these values should be a sequence converging upon the final value).

Comment: The quick answer to finding 3 roots is to look at your plot and pick three different intervals, each containing only one of the roots.  That way you guarantee the root bisection finds is the correct one.  Again, with those other root finding algorithms, they will find one root.  When comparing them, they might not even all converge to the same root, and the convergence depends heavily on the initial condition (or interval, in the case of bisection/secant methods).  For example, if  you happen to initialize one of the methods at the root itself, its performance will be perfect!

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm of bisection method is such that it can only find one root between a defined interval. In your problem, all three roots cannot be found, but if you define different intervals to find out individual roots, you may succeed. You may go through this sample program for [bisection method in Matlab](http://www.codewithc.com/bisection-method-matlab-program) with full theoretical background and example.